# Puma caught an uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, puma

I have a Rails 5.2 application, running fine on my development machine (Mac), but when I uploaded it to my test server, I get an error:

```
Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant User::SessionsController (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

My setup
    Server OS: Ubuntu 18.04
    Nginx
    Rails 5.2.3
    Puma
    Devise

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'puma'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
```

In my config/puma.rb, I have:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
plugin :tmp_restart

if Rails.env != "development"
  app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
  shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
  bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
  stdout_redirect "#{app_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{app_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true
  pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
  state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
  activate_control_app
end
```

Here's what I have in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/xxxxtestserver.com.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/test/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name axxxxtestserver.com.conf;

  root /home/test/public;
  access_log /home/test/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/test/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

This is the first time I use Puma and Nginx. My local dev machine is a Mac running Mojave. When I start the server locally, the application runs fine, it takes me to the login screen.

Based on the error, it seems as if there is a problem with the database, but the error was reported in puma.stderr.log.

I was able to do:

```
rake db:migrate
```

and

```
rake db:seed
```

Without any problems, prior to starting the Rails server, and here's what I see when I start the Rails server:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in test 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
* Listening on unix:///home/test/shared/sockets/puma.sock
* Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1568140299290-2219
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Any ideas?

## Solution:

The issue was that the secret_key_base was not found. In my credentials.yml.enc, I had three sections, production, staging and test and I had added a secret_key_base under each one.

Rails did not like that, and it wanted a single secret_key_base as a top level.

I fixed that by doing (from the home directory):

```
EDITOR="vi" rails credentials:edit
```

The Puma error message is cryptic, and Rails did not produce an error log. I figured it out, when I removed the puma gem, and installed Phusion Passenger. It gave me a very detailed error message, allowing me to fix the problem

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The exception has nothing to do with Puma or Nginx configuration. Please post your `routes.rb` file and the`User::SessionController`, also check that the file exists in the expected location.

Comment: There was no problem with the routes.rb or the sessioncontroller. The issue was that the secret_key_base was not found. I fixed that. The Puma error message is cryptic, and Rails did not produce an error log. I figured it out, when I removed the puma gem, and installed Phusion Passenger. It gave me a very detailed error message.